# Is there a SASS rule for outputting a descendant to the root?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Using SASS & Compass, can you still write in an indented descendant manner but add a rule/command so that the given descendant is written to another level e.g. root?

So this:

```
#example-id-1 {
    background: blue:

    #example-id-2 {
        background: red:

        #example-id-3 {
            background: yellow:
        }

    }

}
```

would normally output this:

```
#example-id-1 { background: blue: }
#example-id-1 #example-id-2 { background: red: }
#example-id-1 #example-id-2 #example-id-3 { background: yellow: }
```

but can a rule be applied to `#example-id-2` or `#example-id-3` so that the output becomes this:

```
#example-id-1 { background: blue: }
#example-id-2 { background: red: }
#example-id-3 { background: yellow: }
```

Many thanks

Comment: SASS is still CSS....just do it as you normally would.

Comment: IDs must be unique so why not style them like in your last example?

Comment: To my knowledge ID's must be unique in the DOM, not CSS, so can be used in a descendant fashion.

Comment: The reason for nesting id's in this way is due to keeping track of a descendent in a visually logical manner. A descendant parent(s) may have a multitude of styles, and descendent siblings (however many that would be) that preceed/proceed may also have many styles, so if you were to remove the descendant and manually place it outside of the parent block, it would make it more time consuming to maintain (lots of scrolling through your CSS file to find the right style.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `@at-root`:

```
#example-id-1 {
    background: blue;

    @at-root #example-id-2 {
        background: red;

        @at-root #example-id-3 {
            background: yellow;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is a Sass 3.3 feature.